# tabletogrid custom hover title

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

I am creating a html table and send it to

```
tableToGrid('#grid', {cmTemplate: {sortable:false}});
```

My orginal html table has structure as below:

```
<tr><th>Month</th><th>Estimate</th></tr>
<tr><td>Aug</td><td>172</td></tr>
<tr><td>Aug</td><td>175</td></tr>
<tr><td>Aug</td><td>165<div class="MyClassWhichInsertsAnIcon"></td></tr>
```

For some cells, I have the Estimated number and for some other cells I have (estimated Number + icon indicating that this is good)
Now when I send this to tabletogrid, I would like the hover to indicate the value and if there is an icon present, I would like the hover to display a custom text "Good Estimate" preferably on icon hover.
The problem I am facing is that the hover displays only the Estimated number even for the cells which contain the icon.

I tried, adding title attribute, span, etc. Any options? Could I customize the hover text here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, I solved this by implementing the custom title code in the AfterInsertRow function. Not exact code, but just to give an idea, I implemented it something like this:

```
 afterInsertRow: function(rowid, data){
        if($( this).hasClass("MyClassWhichInsertsAnIcon")){ 
        var title = 'Custom Title';
        $( this).parent().attr('title', title);
        }
    });
```